# CSS: Sombreamento de "triangulo" criado usando ::after

Tags: css

Criei uma box por css e criei um "triangulo" usando ::after para dar aquele efeitinho da parte de cima maior que a de baixo, só para melhorar a estética mesmo..

simplifiquei o codigo a caráter de estudo:

```
#btn{
font-size: 16px;
color: white;
background-color: black;
padding: 6px 12px;
width: 150px;
height: 36px;
}


#btn::after{
content: '';
margin-top:-6px;
border-right: 40px solid transparent;
border-top: 36px solid  #7e9ee4;
position: absolute;
left: 100%;
}
```

Perfeito, funciona 100%

Agora quis implementar, usar o box-shadow no #btn, esta fazendo a sombra normal, como foi feita a função.
Porém quando tento colocar a sombra no "triangulo" a sobra sempre ficará no quadrado onde foi foi feito este triangulo falso,a minha questão é a seguinte:

Sem usar um fundo png existe há uma forma de fazer esta cor que no código está como 'black' jugar uma sobra para a 'transparent' ou isso, realmente, não é possível ser feito via CSS?

Para exemplificar, segue as 3 situações:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

primeiro: sem sombras

segundo: sombra apenas no #btn

terceiro: sombra no #btn::after

Comment: Rafael. A pergunta é boa mas o ambiente é técnico, não somos rede social, ou fórum de discussões. Somos um site de perguntas e respostas. Evite comprimentos, gírias, pessoalismos e formas muto informais de tratamento.

Comment: obrigado pelas dicas, amigo. Vou me policiar para evitar esses erros novamente. Abraço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o filtro `drop-shadow`, que ao contrário da propriedade `box-shadow`, que cria uma sombra retangular atrás da *caixa* do elemento, cria uma sombra atrás da *forma* do objeto.

Saiba mais na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow).

Assim:

```css
#btn {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  height: 36px;
  
  /* Box-shadow aqui: */
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px red;
}

#btn::after {
  content: '';
  border: solid 15px transparent;
  border-left-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;

  /* Filter com drop-shadow aqui: */
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 2px 2px red);
}
```

```html
<span id="btn">Oi</span>
```

Note que no primeiro exemplo, utilizamos a propriedade `box-shadow` normalmente. No segundo, o [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) com o efeito `drop-shadow`.

Comment: Perfeito Luiz! Muito obrigado por me ajudar a evoluir e pela indicação de leitura. Realmente não acreditava que tivesse uma limitação tão básica, por isso recorri aos senhores. Testei e funcionou corretamente! Mais uma vez agradeço. Abraço!